# absolutePath of file

Tags: java, file, path

I'm searching a file in my system but this file may have different paths under other systems, means when I'm searching `file.txt` its all the time under /f1/f2/file.txt but for a system to another it can be like so `c:/programme/f1/f2/file.txt` in one system but `d:/system/f1/f2/file.txt`
I tried this but it doesn't read the absolute Path

```
String filename = "file.txt";
Path path = Paths.get("\\f1\\f2\\");
Path absPath= path.toAbsolutePath(); 
File file = new File(absPath, filename);
```

and then I'm just getting `c:\f1\f2\file.txt`, or it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

## tl; dr

Remove the backslash / -es before `f1\\f2\\`, it prevents / they prevent the correct resolution of the parent path.

**Example:**

The following code resolves the given root path (as long as possible by your example) with the intermediate path and the filename:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "file.txt";

    // your problem was leading backslash here
    Path subPath = Paths.get("f1\\f2");

    // create the root paths
    Path rootOnC = Paths.get("c:\\programme");
    Path rootOnD = Paths.get("d:\\system");

    // resolve the subpaths and the filename on the root paths
    Path fullPathOnC = rootOnC.resolve(subPath).resolve(fileName);
    Path fullPathOnD = rootOnD.resolve(subPath).resolve(fileName);

    // print the toString representation of their absolute path
    System.out.println("[C:]\t" + fullPathOnC.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    System.out.println("[D:]\t" + fullPathOnD.toAbsolutePath().toString());
}
```

The output is this:

```
[C:]    c:\programme\f1\f2\file.txt
[D:]    d:\system\f1\f2\file.txt
```

## EDIT

In case you want to search the file tree for a known subpath, you can implement a `java.nio.file.FileVisitor` like this one:

```
class PathFinder implements FileVisitor<Path> {

    private Path subPathToBeFound;

    public PathFinder(Path subPathToBeFound) {
        this.subPathToBeFound = subPathToBeFound;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (file.endsWith(subPathToBeFound)) {
            // print the full path that contained the given subpath
            System.out.println("Subpath found in " + file.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
        } else {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        System.err.println("Visit failed: " + exc.getMessage());
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

}
```

and use it somehow similar to this minimal example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "file.txt";

    // resolve the file name on the subpath
    Path subPath = Paths.get("f1\\f2").resolve(fileName);

    // create a file visitor
    PathFinder pf = new PathFinder(subPath);

    /*
     * this example finds all available drives programmatically
     * and walks the file tree of each one
     */
    try {
        for (Path root : FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
            System.out.println("Searching in " + root.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            Files.walkFileTree(root, pf);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The result would be either a full walk without result (in case the subpath is not present on the drive) or a simple print output like this one:

```
Subpath found in C:\programme\f1\f2\file.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't have to give the root cause maybe I will work on another system where f1/f2/file.txt is under G:/windows/f1/f2/file.txt for example. I have a part from the path that is /f1/f2/file.txt and the program have to know where it exist

Comment: @ElyMan OK, then you will have to implement a `SimpleFileVisitor<Path>` and walk the file tree until you find any subpath equal to `f1\\f2\\file.txt`...

Comment: @ElyMan I provided an example, please have a look at it.

Comment: thank you for the effort but that's my problem I don't know if there are under c:/ or d:/ and with this "Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("C:\\"), pf);" will never work if the files I'm searching for are under z:/ for example

Comment: @ElyMan OK, then check my edit of the bottom example in my answer, it now checks all available drives.